# Given $a,b,c>0$ and $a^5+b^5+c^5=3$. Is $a+b+c\leq 3$ always true?

Tags: inequality

> Given $a,b,c>0$ and $a^5+b^5+c^5=3$. Is $a+b+c\leq 3$ always true?

I tried many ways to prove it and to find a counterexample, but I couldn't. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It is true, by power mean inequality for example. Or $a^5 + 4 \ge 5a$.

Comment: @Sanchez: Can you please explain more?

Comment: It's AM-GM: $a^5 + 4 = a^5 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$ with 5 terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to prove this.

One way is to use the fact the $2^{nd}$ derivative of $x^5$ is $20 x^3 > 0$ for all $x > 0$. This means $x^5$ is a strictly convex function over the interval $(0,\infty)$.
By [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), we have:

$$1 = \frac{a^5 + b^5 + c^5}{3} \ge \left(\frac{a + b + c}{3}\right)^5\implies 3 \ge a+b+c \tag{*1}$$

The [power mean inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality) mentioned in others' comment can be viewed as a special case
of Jensen's inequality. For 3 variables $a,b,c > 0$ and exponents $p > q > 0$, the power
mean inequality has the form:

$$\left(\frac{a^p + b^p + c^p}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \ge
  \left(\frac{a^q + b^q + c^q}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

One can rewrite it as
$$\frac{(a^q)^{p/q} + (b^q)^{p/q} + (c^q)^{p/q}}{3} \ge
  \left(\frac{a^q + b^q + c^q}{3}\right)^{p/q}\tag{*2}$$

If one plug $p = 5, q = 1$ into $(*2)$, one obtain the same inequality in L.H.S of $(*1)$. This means one can prove your inequality using power mean inequality alone. It also suggest one can derive the power mean inequality from Jensen's inequality
by considering the function $x^{\frac{p}{q}}$ at 3 points $a^q, b^q$ and $c^q$.